# I can't import SQL to database in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, rake

To be organized I want to have a file `db/seeds/countries.rb` with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("db/sql/countries_iso3166.sql"))
```

And this file `db/sql/countries_iso3166.sql` has a SQL that when I paste in server it runs successfully, but when I run it with `rake db:seed` I get:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'INSERT INTO `countries` (`code`, `alpha2`, `alpha3`, `langCS`, `langDE`, `langEN'
at line 34:
```

These are lines 34 and 35:

```
34  INSERT INTO `countries` (`code`, `alpha2`, `alpha3`, `langCS`, `langDE`, `langEN`,
    `langES`, `langFR`, `langIT`, `langNL`) VALUES
35  (4, 'AF', 'AFG', 'Afghanistán', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afganistán',
    'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan'),
```

Comment: Not sure but could the encoding be a problem? Just thought about it when I read the way the last A is written in 'Afghanistán'. Just a hunch.

Comment: Yes, it could be, but encoding of what? I don't understand how encoding works exactly. I suppose you mean I need to set encoding, maybe in my seed file, right? how could I do that.

Comment: Do you have the sql file you want to import from?

Comment: yes, but I converted all this code to ruby, I don't have anymore the problem.

Comment: @juanpastas i am facing the same issue, can you help?